# How to run the iScroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've decided to give the JavaScript library iScroll a try. I've run into some problems though. I just don't seem to get things to work as they are intended to. The basic setup is not written with jQuery in mind but this is how I believe it should be called.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
            scrollX: true, 
            scrollY: false, 
            scrollbars: true,
            mouseWheel: true,
            interactiveScrollbars: true,
            shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
            fadeScrollbars: true
        });
        myScroll();
    });
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

The documentation tells me this is the way add options to the code but somehow I can't get the scroll bars to render at all. I would also like to add a fade-out of a div based on the momentarily position of the scroll, ie. not the position when the scroll stops. This is how the scrollEnd position is called, but how do I get the position on the fly, ie. How do I trigger the fade-out when scrolling passes left -10, regardless if the scroll has stopped or not?

```
    myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function () {
        if ( this.x < -10 ) {
            $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast');
        } else {
            $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle to isolate the problem?

Comment: Why are you doing `myScroll();`?

Comment: P.S. `document.addEventListener('touchmove'` can be `$(document).on('touchmove'`

Comment: This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Coffer/bymcma6c/2/). Unfortunately it seems as my example won't work at all - perhaps you can point in the direction of fixing both the error preventing from running at all but also guide me to the solution of asked problems?

Comment: I was under the impression that `var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {options});` only declared (in this instance) a new object? Or does that line both declare the IScroll-object (myScroll) and call for execution of the object at the same time?

Comment: @KristoferGisslén: It creates a new object, yes.  That object isn't a function, however ("execution of the object" doesn't make any sense).